# Is it possible to refine the parameters of a model by optimizing on something other than performance?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter, tuning

Suppose I have a model with some parameters which I want to tune so that the model performs better on some task. If I understand correctly, many supervised learning methods will train the model and refine the parameters by optimizing the models performance on the training set for the task.

Is it possible to refine the parameters of the model by optimizing on something other than performance on the given task (say, performance on a different but similar task or some feature of the dataset), and if so is there a name for this paradigm/distinction between the two paradigms?

Comment: That’s multi-target learning https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02352

Comment: Can you elaborate on the motivation for optimizing performance on something other than the original task? Is it because hypothetically you don't have data on the actual task?

Comment: It may be the case that for some reason it is hard to train on data from the original task, for example if not much data exists. I imagine this might be the case in some natural language tasks, where a model might be able to learn about the semantics of the terms from annotation data but not the actual task